# How to create a FirebaseAuth User from a query from his UID?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am a bit puzzled about how the Users are managed.

My app successfully creates user accounts via FirebaseAuth whom are creating classified ads.

I need to fetch the owner of the ad from the User UID and so far my code is as follows:

```dart
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>?> getUser(String uid) async {
    final d = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("User")
        .where("id", isEqualTo: uid)
        .get();

    if (d.docs.isEmpty) return null;

    return d.docs.first.data();
  }
```

This code is expected to fetch the given user as a map.

And now, I'd like to convert the `Map<String,dynamic>` as an actual User instance. But how I should do that?

And is it the right way to go? Because I am wondering whether the `User` should only be dedicated to the 'authenticated self'.

Comment: Can you share an example of the result on `d.docs.first`?

Comment: Is `User` a model? Or, do you mean the `User` of the `firebase_auth` package?

Comment: The collection named "User" is a collection which you created yourself? If you'd like to query the user database managed by Firebase it won't work.

Comment: What I call the User is the FirebaseAuth user, right.

Comment: @PeterKoltai I am talking about the Firebase User. How can I query this base then?

Comment: You can't. The suggested way is to have an own user's collection, keep it in sync using Firebase authentication triggers (Cloud Functions), and use this copy if you need to query the users.

Comment: Thank you very much @PeterKoltai . Do you have any URL I can inspire from?

Comment: Check [this out](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/extend-with-functions), it is pretty straightforward, you add an `onCreate` and an `onDelete` trigger. But keep in mind to set proper rules to Firestore on this collection.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm right, do you mean the `User` of the [`firebase_auth`](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth) package? You cannot convert `Map<String, dynamic>` to `User`. My opinion is to convert it to a model. Take a look at the example below:

```
class UserModel {
  UserModel(
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.email,
    …
  );

  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String email;
  …

  factory UserModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data, String documentId) {
    final String? name = data["name"];
    final String? email = data["email"];
    …

    return UserModel(
      documentId,
      name ?? "",
      email ?? "",
      …
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "name": name,
        "email": email,
        …
      };
}
```

---

```
UserModel.fromMap(d.docs.first.data(), d.docs.first.id),
```

---

```
UserModel(
  "Name",
  "Email",
  …
).toMap(),
```